# NoMethodError ------------- undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: chef-infra

```rb
cache_path = Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]

puts "=========================="
test1 = ::File.join("#{cache_path}\\#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['windows_pkg']}")
puts test1

reboot 'restart_server' do
  action :nothing
  reason 'Reboot is necessary!'
end

remote_file ::File.join("#{cache_path}\\#{rd_exe}") do
  source ::File.join("#{node['test-citrix-agents']['windows_source']}/#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['windows_pkg']}")
  headers ({"username"=>"artifactory_username", "password"=>"artifactory_api_key"})
  checksum "#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['checksum']}"
  action :create_if_missing
  not_if { ::File.exists?(::File.join("#{cache_path}\\#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['windows_pkg']}") }
end
```

Have been compiling now for few days ! Not sure whats wrong with this. Please rescue me

Comment: Could you add more context to your question? Things like what and how you are doing would help. Also, when are you getting the errors?

Comment: Thanks  -> I am using the remote_file here to download the source files from the artifactory which is actually a .exe windows installer file, the headers mentioned in the code are from the dependencies. The berks install shows positive, eventually when i started executing the kitchen converge, i have been seeing the nomethod error on chefdk.

Comment: This is chefdk  -> a recipe to download a file and install on a windows machine.

Comment: I can see 2 distince uses of [] (ie in indexer) in your resource. When you are getting values from your node object - check that all the attributes you expect to be there are. I'm not that experienced with chef debuggin so i just log things... but there might a better way.
The second place I see '[] is the action of your remote file, `[:create]`. Like I said I'm no chef pro, but I've not seen it written like that before, I would except it to be `action :create`

Comment: @Dave Yes I have been using puts across the recipe & tried to see if there are any typos or do they show up as they should be etc, but no luck !  & secondly [:create] implies :create and is more formal way of using it. I have tried that option and for the sake of testing i used it here as [:create]

Comment: Net::HTTPServerException
           ------------------------
           401 "Unauthorized"

           Resource Declaration:
           ---------------------
           # In C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test-citrix-agents/recipes/redistributable_64.rb

Comment: 20: remote_file ::File.join("#{cache_path}\\#{rd_exe}") do
            21:    source ::File.join("#{node['test-citrix-agents']['windows_source']}/#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['windows_pkg']}")
            22:    headers ({"username"=>"artifactory_username", "password"=>"artifactory_api_key"})
            23:    checksum "#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['checksum']}"
            24:    action :create_if_missing
            25:    not_if { ::File.exists?(::File.join("#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['windows_pkg']}\\vc_redist.x64.exe")) }
            26: end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the problem resolved

- use Ruby block to identify the nil class - in this case there was dependency to receive secret from a different cookbook and looks like it was generating an empty class until it was corrected by just adding only those cookbooks those are necessary
- headers( "Authorization"=>"Basic #{ Base64.encode64("#{username}:#{password}").gsub("\n", "") }" )
  Headers used to solve the problem -> with hard coded userID and password for testing
- the kitchen yml file was the major factor, the namespace set makes lot of difference. For one of the line items extra space caused nomethod error despite all the above corrections

Comment: You should really stop using File.join and only use string interpolation:  `::File.join("#{cache_path}\\#{rd_exe}")` can be written just as `"#{cache_path}\\#{rd_exe}"` or you can use `File.join(cache_path, rd_exe)` but that only uses forward slashes (ruby on windows happily accepts forward slashes in all APIs, but if you send those paths to Windows you'll need backslashes and File.join is unix/ruby-centric and does not do that).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure using `node.default` to assign values to variables will work. This is usually used when we want to set a value to a node variable in a recipe.

Example:

```
node.default['my_cookbook']['var'] = 'somevalue'
```

Whereas when you want to assign the value of node variable to another variable:

```
dload_checksum = node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['checksum']
rd_path = "C:\\agents\\#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['windows_pkg']}"
dload_source = "#{node['test-citrix-agents']['windows_source']}/#{node['ms_redistributable_2017_64']['windows_pkg']}"
```

Also, in your `remote_file` resource, you can use the variables defined above:

```
    checksum dload_checksum
    not_if { ::File.exists?(rd_path) }
```

*Update*:

Apart from the stack trace, can you update the question with `Cookbook Trace` and `Relevant File Content:` that is shown during the run?

Something similar to:

```
Cookbook Trace: (most recent call first)
----------------------------------------
  C:/Chef/cache/cookbooks/cookbook1/recipes/default.rb:28:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
C:/Chef/cache/cookbooks/cookbook1/recipes/default.rb:

 26:  end
 27:
 28>> node['cookbook1']['var'].each do |var|
 29:    file "c:/Users/Public/#{var}" do
```

Comment: I have been doing it as Node but later gave a try with node.default based on some post on stack. Yes I did all that checksum etc. I just wanted to keep the code short while posting

Comment: The error suggests that there is a `nil` value where an array operation is performed. The `remote_file` resource accepts `source` as array (which you are using).

It might be a good idea to "debug" all 3 variables inside a `ruby_block` using `puts`. Looking at the compiled resource during execution, Chef would indicate the problematic line with `>>`.

Comment: Thanks :), yes exactly - there definitely is nil -> but I really dont know how to correct that. Lets say node attribute value set as node[cookbook][base_url]="https://artifactory.com/package" and then when I use this remote_file - > it shows this as the problem after so many ruby_block I tried.

Comment: NoMethodError
       -------------
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: [2020-07-26T17:08:42+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       Running handlers complete
       [2020-07-26T17:08:42+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
       [2020-07-26T17:08:42+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/Users/vagrant/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       [2020-07-26T17:08:42+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
       [2020-07-26T17:08:42+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Have you tried using the values directly in the `remote_file` resource? Like `source 'artifactory.com/package'`, `checksum 'duej36h67hy..'` instead of variables?

Comment: Great ! let me add everything directly than passing on variables as you said. But meanwhile as you mentioned earlier, I remove the .default mentioned in the recipe. Then puts for every Mash and then i stumbled upon something strange -> One of the dependencies i had to set on a cookbook was throwing NIl. So I had to make some changes to berfile, kitchen to make sure the right URL is being used. Despite all these efforts it continued with the same error. One more info -> Berks install -> No issues seen.

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you update your question with those details?

Comment: Yes @seshadri  I just did that. This is the latest edit of the code . The stack trace shows error on remote_File and headers at the moment

Comment: `headers` takes a Hash as parameter. Is this `artifactory_basic_auth` variable a hash? You would have to pass it as: `header( {'username' => 'user', 'password' => 'changeit'} )`

Comment: They are linked to a cookbook called libraries. When I puts the node['base'] - they throw the ID and password as hash. Then Node[base]... is part of default attribute. Let me try this out

Comment: ================================================================================
           Error executing action `create_if_missing` on resource 'remote_file[C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache\vc_redist.x64.exe]'
           ================================================================================

           Net::HTTPServerException
           ------------------------
           401 "Unauthorized"

Comment: Check the official documentation for remote_file: https://docs.chef.io/resources/remote_file/, it has some more examples on passing the headers.

Comment: Yes Sure, I just now pasted the chef run

Comment: Thanks Seshadri so much  for saving my day -

Comment: Welcome Chetan!